# Python call doskey macro

Tags: python, windows, shell, macros

I'm not entirely sure what's going on with this script, but basically this is what I'm trying to do:

I have a Windows batch script that uses the doskey command to define some macros. In Python, I wish to call one of these macros. On one system, I am able to do this but on the other it tells me it is not a valid command. Yet, on both systems, if I call "doskey /macros" I see all the macros properly defined.

Through python I'm attempting to call the macro simply with the subprocess call command:

```
from subprocess import call
call( "some_macro", shell=True )
```

As mentioned, this works just fine on one system, but not the other (both running Windows 7 64-bit).

I'm aware I could get around this by making the call directly in Python instead of trying to call the macro, but I want to understand why this isn't working even though the shell context python gets seems to have the macro properly defined (as observed by running the doskey /macro command).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you check to make sure the computer is plugged in?

Comment: What I meant by the previous comment was - is this a python problem? Or is it something basic like the systems configured differently? Same OS doesn't necessarily mean same environment.

Comment: Ah, see, that's not exactly the same thing. They're both relatively clean installations of Windows 7 with the same versions of Python. Aside from that, I couldn't imagine what would affect the Windows command prompt. Nor can I imagine why running doskey /macros would show all the valid, properly defined macros, yet I cannot actually run one of them. If you have any ideas as to what environment settings might affect this, that would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to accept the inferior nature of the Windows shell and simply embed my commands in Python instead.

Not exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: Can you please provide more information where the issue was and how did yo fix it?